# Multiple condition in one line flutter || null as a null or null as a String like "null"

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, if-statement, null

**Error**
The operands of the operator '||' must be assignable to 'bool'.

```
 hintText: _response?.Name.toString() != null || "null" ? _response?.Name.toString(): 'Enter Name',
```

I got an error in this line after the second condition, actually, the problem is sometime null is == **null**, and sometimes null is coming as a string like **"null"**, so I have to add a condition in hint text any type of null did not show on a string if null coming from the backend so its showing enter name.

Comment: `|| "null" ? `this part is not a condition evaluation. You should match it to something, e.g. `variable == null`

Comment: "sometimes null is coming as a string like "null"".  Figure out why and fix that instead of papering over the problem.  Treating the string `'null'` as `null`, especially for a name, will cause problems for [people who actually have "Null" as a name](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/).  Once you fix that, then you can simplify your expression to `response?.Name.toString() ?? 'Enter Name'`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 hintText: _response?.Name.toString() != null || "null" ? _response?.Name.toString(): 'Enter Name',
```

to

```
 hintText: _response?.Name != null  ? _response?.Name.toString(): 'Enter Name',
```